Time enabled rasters in ArcGIS Online
Looking for some guidance on being able to create a radar image loop of time enabled rasters in ArcGIS Online. I can create a loop of rasters in ArcGIS Pro with time enabled, but as soon as I try and export as a tile or anything else there is no time ability brought over into ArcGIS Online.
Is this something that can be done with rasters or can time only be enabled on Vector files in ArcGIS Online?

Have you researched on the esri community website rather than here? I found this Q&A.
